# How can I use HTML and Javascript together to change the variable value?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a variable, I created a button that I'll press and change the variable value. How can I perform it?

```
<html>
<body>
<button>
    Button
</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a = 0;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add an onclick handler to the button :

```html
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="setA()">
    Button
</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a = 0;
    function setA(){
      a=4;
      console.log(a);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it, every time but is pressed var a would be re-initialized.

Comment: you mean like set to 0 beforehand ? cause I tried with a++ instead and it just keeps increasing oO

Comment: Yes jonathan. The correct would be set a=0 in a script other than that linked to button, before this one. So you initialize once and everytime but is pressed then proceed with desired calculation.

Comment: not sure what you mean but the script tag is only running once only the setA function is called onclick

Comment: Hey, I want to ask a little question, how do I add a text after pressing the button, for example instead of adding it to console chat?

Comment: like a new element displaying some text ?

Comment: I tried to use document.write but it just deleted everything in <body>.

Comment: use `let element=document.createElement('tag');element.textContent='sometag';document.body.appendChild(element)`  instead (also kinda a new question)

Comment: Thanks Jonathan Heindl, this is what I was talking about, how do I reflesh or clear it? It just keep adding value as a string like if I press the button and variable equal to 1, it will show "11", then "111" etc., and not 1.

Comment: in this case its probably better to update the element instead of adding new ones

Comment: let prev=document.getElementById('myButtonSomeID');if(prev==null){
let element=document.createElement('tag');element.textContent='sometag';
element.id="myButtonSomeID";
document.body.appendChild(element);prev=element}
prev.textContent="newTExt";

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, you're great programmer :)

Comment: I will learn HTML, JavaScript, CSS gradually. My only language I know good is GML to be honest.